# Flutter: Stateful Widget does not update

Tags: flutter, dart, state, rebuild, statefulwidget

Imagine two Widgets: Main that manages a tabbar and therefore holds several Widgets - and Dashboard.
On Main Constructor I create a first Instance of Dashboard and the other tabbar Widgets with some dummy data (they are getting fetched in the meanwhile in initState). I **build** these with Futurebuilder. Once the data arrived I want to create a new Instance of Dashboard, but it won't change.

```
class _MainState extends State<HomePage> {
  var _tabs = <Widget>[];
  Future<dynamic> futureData;

  _MainState() {
    _tabs.add(Dashboard(null));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = _getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: futureData,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            tabs[0] = Dashboard(snapshot.data);
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

```
class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final  data;

  DashboardScreen(this.data,
      {Key key})
      : super(key: key) {
    print('Dashboard Constructor: ' + data.toString());
  }

  @override
  _DashboardScreenState createState() => _DashboardScreenState(data);
}


class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  var data;

  _DashboardScreenState(this.data);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('InitState: ' + data.toString());
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Widget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    print('didUpdateWidget');
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    print('didChangeDependencies' + data.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(data.toString());
  }
}
```

When I print on several available methods it comes clear that the DasboardScreenState is not recreated. Only the DashboardScreen Constructor is called again when the data arrived, but not it's state...

flutter: MainConstructor: null

flutter: Dashboard Constructor: null

flutter: InitState: null

flutter: didChangeDependencies: null

flutter: Dashboard Constructor: MachineStatus.Manual   <- Here the data arrived in futureBuilder

How can I force the State to recreate? I tried to use the key parameter with UniqueKey(), but that didn't worked. Also inherrited widget seems not to be the solution either, despite the fact that i don't know how to use it in my use case, because the child is only available in the ..ScreenState but not the updated data..

I could imagine to inform dashboardScreenState by using Stream: listen to messages and then call setState() - I think, but that's only a workaround.

Can anyone help me please :)?

Answer (score 0):

I know I have had issues with the if statement before, try:

```
return FutureBuilder(
    future: futureData,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) { //use hasData
        DataType data  = snapshot.data; //Declare Values first
        tabs[0] = Dashboard(data);
      } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    });
```

Comment: You must not call setState() or markNeedsBuild() within the build. 
Already tried that..

Comment: I  have modified my answer -  take a  look

Comment: Still not working :/
I also tried to assign the snapshot data to local variables hold in main and pass them into the first and second instance of Dashboard. So that the first instance gets null values and the second the received data. 
Does not work too..